# NPM error al instalar cualquier paquete

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm, ssl

Estoy tratando de instalar Angular/CLI y me surge este problema con NPM:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que este error no me pasa **solo** con angular, cuando intento instalar cualquier otro paquete, me surge el mismo error.
He probado varias cosas, entre ellas reinstalar node.js, cambiar de versión, cambiar de 32 bits a 64 y viceversa, instalar openssl...

Nada me ha funcionado, siempre es el mismo error.
Sé que no es tema de la red ni de mi router ya que un portatil en la misma red (instalado de 0 todo igual que en el pc principal) me funciona perfectamente.

Os dejo por aquí también el log completo.

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.5.1
2 info using node@v18.16.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\lfernandez\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\lfernandez\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load Completed in 7ms
16 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 7ms
17 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
19 verbose title npm install @angular/cli
20 verbose argv "install" "--global" "@angular/cli"
21 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
23 timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms
24 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\lfernandez\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-06T15_17_08_653Z-
25 verbose logfile C:\Users\lfernandez\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-06T15_17_08_653Z-debug-0.log
26 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 9ms
27 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
28 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load Completed in 23ms
30 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 timing idealTree:init Completed in 5ms
35 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 3ms
36 silly idealTree buildDeps
37 silly fetch manifest @angular/cli@*
38 silly placeDep ROOT @angular/cli@ OK for:  want: *
39 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 70133ms
40 timing idealTree:node_modules/@angular/cli Completed in 0ms
41 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 70133ms
42 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms
43 timing idealTree Completed in 70142ms
44 timing command:install Completed in 70148ms
45 verbose type system
46 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: write EPROTO 44130000:error:0A00042E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 70
46 verbose stack
46 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
46 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
46 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
46 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
46 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
46 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
46 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
47 verbose cwd C:\Windows\system32
48 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
49 verbose node v18.16.0
50 verbose npm  v9.5.1
51 error code EPROTO
52 error syscall write
53 error errno EPROTO
54 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: write EPROTO 44130000:error:0A00042E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 70
54 error
55 verbose exit 1
56 timing npm Completed in 70189ms
57 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1686064628692
58 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1686064628695
59 verbose code 1
60 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
60 error     C:\Users\lfernandez\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-06T15_17_08_653Z-debug-0.log
```

Configuración de openssl:

```
HOME            = .
openssl_conf = openssl_init
config_diagnostics = 1
oid_section = new_oids
[ new_oids ]
tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7
[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect
[provider_sect]
default = default_sect
[default_sect]
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        
[ CA_default ]
dir     = ./demoCA      
certs       = $dir/certs        
crl_dir     = $dir/crl      
database    = $dir/index.txt    
new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts     
certificate = $dir/cacert.pem   
serial      = $dir/serial       
crlnumber   = $dir/crlnumber    
crl     = $dir/crl.pem      
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem 
x509_extensions = usr_cert      
name_opt    = ca_default        
cert_opt    = ca_default        
default_days    = 365           
default_crl_days= 30            
default_md  = default       
preserve    = no            
policy      = policy_match
[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional
[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes      = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extensions to add to the self signed cert
string_mask = utf8only
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = AU
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2
stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Some-State
localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max          = 64
emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_max        = 64
[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20
unstructuredName        = An optional company name
[ usr_cert ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
[ v3_ca ]
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
[ crl_ext ]
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always
[ proxy_cert_ext ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo
[ tsa ]
default_tsa = tsa_config1   
[ tsa_config1 ]
dir     = ./demoCA      
serial      = $dir/tsaserial    
crypto_device   = builtin       
signer_cert = $dir/tsacert.pem  
certs       = $dir/cacert.pem   
signer_key  = $dir/private/tsakey.pem 
signer_digest  = sha256         
default_policy  = tsa_policy1       
other_policies  = tsa_policy2, tsa_policy3  
digests     = sha1, sha256, sha384, sha512 
accuracy    = secs:1, millisecs:500, microsecs:100  
clock_precision_digits  = 0 
ordering        = yes   
tsa_name        = yes   
ess_cert_id_chain   = no    
ess_cert_id_alg     = sha1      
[insta] 
server = pki.certificate.fi:8700
path = pkix/
recipient = "/C=FI/O=Insta Demo/CN=Insta Demo CA" 
ignore_keyusage = 1 
unprotected_errors = 1 
extracertsout = insta.extracerts.pem
ref = 3078 
secret = pass:insta # can be used for both client and server side
cmd = ir 
subject = "/CN=openssl-cmp-test"
newkey = insta.priv.pem
out_trusted = apps/insta.ca.crt 
certout = insta.cert.pem
[pbm] 
ref = $insta::ref 
secret = $insta::secret 
[signature]
trusted = $insta::out_trusted
secret =
key = $insta::newkey 
cert = $insta::certout 
[ir]
cmd = ir
[cr]
cmd = cr
[kur]
cmd = kur
oldcert = $insta::certout 
[rr]
cmd = rr
oldcert = $insta::certout
```

Comment: Qué versión de NodeJS estás usando?

Comment: Hola, estoy usando la 18.16.0 pero también he probado con la 20.2 y el resultado es exactamente el mismo...

Comment: Es extraño porque sí es un error de SSL. Está usando en el handshake un protocolo que ya no soporta el servidor (TLSv1) y por eso falla (el error 70 siempre es fatal), pero [ellos dicen](https://nodejs.dev/en/api/v18/tls/#modifying-the-default-tls-cipher-suite) que la suite de algoritmos de cifrado que trae node funciona perfecto... Por favor revisa e incluye en la pregunta tu `.npmrc` y cualquier configuración de openssl que hayas hecho (`openssl.cnf`). Revisa que no haya actualizaciones de Windows pendientes. PD. Si tu PC funciona a 64bit, deberías usar la versión correspondiente.

Comment: Hola,
sólo tengo esta opción activada:
strict-ssl=false

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo problema que tú con todos los paquetes que quiero instalar. Incluso me sale el mismo error. Alguien que pueda ayudar. También he probado con varias versiones de npm, cuál sería la mejor?

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).